# Допустимо ли в прямой речи ставить перед словами автора точку вместо запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

— Я подумаю об этом. — Сказала она.
— Я подумаю об этом, — сказала она.

Какого варианта всегда стоит придерживаться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Недопустимо.* Придерживаться надо **второго** варианта.

[Вот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=157#pp157) где об этом говорится у Розенталя:

> § 49. Прямая речь перед словами автора
>
> Если прямая речь стоит перед словами автора, то после нее ставятся **запятая** (вопросительный или восклицательный знак, многоточие) и тире; причем слова автора пишутся со строчной буквы:
>
> ***«Мать, наверное, не спит, а я с работы не возвращаюсь»,** — думал Павка* (Н. О.)
> ...
> То же при оформлении прямой речи с абзаца:
>
> ***— Лесть и трусость — самые дурные пороки,** — громко промолвила Ася* (Т.)

В вашем случае видится два варианта: ваш второй пример *при оформлении **с абзаца*** и следующий вариант *при оформлении **в строку**.*

> ***«Я подумаю об этом»,** — сказала она.*

Comment: Спасибо:) слишком многие так делают

Comment: Не за что) К счастью, пока не встречал такого.

Answer (score 0):

В ряде случаев такая пунктуация допустима и является даже лучшим из возможных решений.

> — Погоди-ка, — понял руку он.
>
> — Погоди-ка. — Он поднял руку.

В чём разница? Разница в том, что в первом случае автор рассматривает свою ремарку как описание процесса произнесения самой фразы. Чаще всего для этого служат невыразительные слова «сказал», «ответил», «отозвался». Унылые авторы заменяют их на не банальные «кивнул» и «улыбнулся», отчего все в книге только улыбаются и кивают (а иногда ещё и кивают головой, что вообще  убийственно). Ну, а самые изобретательные прибегают вот к таким действиям-высказываниям. Хорошо это представлено, например, в прозе Есенина. Такие ремарки всегда выступают в качестве авторского пояснения.

Во втором случае мы имеем дело с отдельным предложением (а бывает, что и текстом). Здесь нет инверсии, которая обязательно присутствует в связанных с фразой ремарках. Такую авторскую речь вполне можно писать и с новой строки. В таких случаях точка обязательна. Запятой там нечего делать. А почему, собственно, не писать с новой строки? Причин две: 1) Действия всё же связаны, так что особо разрывать их, множа абзацы в три слова, нет смысла; 2) Фраза персонажа может продолжиться, например:

> — Погоди-ка. — Он поднял руку. — Куда это вы собрались?

Такую пунктуацию можно встретить во многих художественных произведениях. Очень её любят отечественные издатели Стивена Кинга. Там оно встречается всюду. И это лучшее из решений. Вот Булгаков в "Собачьем сердце" решил эту проблему иначе — скобочками. Но ведь скобки, включённые в прямую речь, дают повод рассмотреть их как интонационно выделенную часть самой прямой речи. Вариант с тире логичнее и однозначнее.

Comment: Это немного другой случай, у автора глагол речи "сказала", его роль - вводить или заключать прямую речь, а в Вашем  примере - глагол физического действия, это действие после речевой ситуации.

Comment: @Людмила я дал автору более широкое представление о ходе рассуждения при выборе пунктуации. В вопросе не конкретизировано, что загвоздка только в приведённом автором примере. Я понимаю, что вопрос задан в целом, о принципе.

Comment: И да. Неверно говорить, что "поднял руку он" или "он поднял руку" – действие ПОСЛЕ речевой ситуации. Это действие ВО ВРЕМЯ речевой ситуации.